# Using '{' as a string in the format method python

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I want to be able to print something like such "{x}" using the format method, but the nature of the curly braces is messing me up.

I tried

```
'{{}}'.format(x)
```

however that returned a value error. Is there a way to tell python that the curly brace is meant to be used as a string rather than an argument for the format?

Answer (score 6):

`{{` is converted into `{`by `format`, so use this:

```
'{{{}}}'.format(x)
```

(note the *three* braces)

However, in this case, I would use the older C-style format string:

```
'{%s}' % x
```

It is a lot clearer.